How to override HikariCP datasource parameters for springboot application?
I have a SpringBoot application where I have two primary Database source . If the connection to primary does not work, the application should connect to the secondary data sources.
I have configured
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=300
but I see a delay of 30 seconds before the application connects to the secondary datasource. When I turned the debug log on by adding the following lines in application.properties,
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE

I see that actually the default connectionTimeoutValue=30000 is taken. How can I override this from application.properties. I also tried
spring.datasource.connection-timeout

but I stll see the default values in the debug. even the maximumPoolSize or any other properties are not set from the application.properties
I am on SpringBoot 2.7. How can I override the default parameters?
This is in my application.properties
## HikariCP settings
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=debug
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=300
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=300
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariPoolBooks
spring.datasource.db1.jdbcUrls=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB1NamePrimary;username;password,\
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBNameSecondary;xxxx;yyyy
spring.datasource.db2.jdbcUrls=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB2NamePrimary;username;password,\
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBNameSecondary;xxxx;yyyy

The bean is as below, I have a file for configuration of DB1 and a separate 1 for DB2.
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db1")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {""},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = BEAN_DB1_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        transactionManagerRef = BEAN_DB1_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
@EntityScan({""})
public class DB1DatasourceConfig {

@Bean(name = DB1_DATABASE_CONNECTION_BEAN)
    public DataSourceConnectionBean Db1ConnectionBean(){
        if(Db1ConnectionBeanInstance == null){
            Db1ConnectionBeanInstance = new DataSourceConnectionBean();
        }
        return Db1ConnectionBeanInstance;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties pgsqlDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(BEAN_DB1_DATA_SOURCE)
    @DependsOn(DB1_DATABASE_CONNECTION_BEAN)
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db1")
    public DataSource db1DataSource() throws SQLException {
        //bunch of code here to get URL for each instance
        //calls createDataSource
        return createDatasource(url, index)
    }
    
    private DataSource createDatasource(String url, int index) throws SQLException {
       
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(ORG_POSTGRESQL_DRIVER);
        dataSourceBuilder.url(urlParts[0]);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(urlParts[1]);
        
        dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
        DataSource ds= dataSourceBuilder.build();
        return ds;
    }

}


You cannot have 2 primary datasources (in the sense of @Primary). The spring.datasource. is only useful if you are actually binding to it. Please add your configuration properties as well as the beans you have added.

They are for different purposes. You can assume that I have just 1 primary and can have some of the secondary DBs. I am not able to get it right even with that setup

You aren't using the DataSourceProperties to create the datasource as you should. So those properties aren't being set, simply because your own code is ignoring them, you are bypassing the auto-configuration features here. Let your createDatasource use those properties (and use the proper binding with spring.datasource.db1 instead of spring.datasource. Which is basically explained here as well (the official documentation).

Thankyou for looking at it. Can you tell me what is missing? I am new to SpringBoot and I did not write this code. Can you point me to some where I can learn it form?

I pointed you to the exact section in the official documentation. So please read the comment before asking what was already given.
